# How to convert an Array of Objects into a single Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I convert an array that contains multiple objects to a single object

I want to convert something like this :

```
    [

      {
        'Kyber': {tokenSymbol: 'DAI', avgPrice: 1}
      },
      

      {
       'Bamboo Relay': {tokenSymbol: 'DAI',avgPrice: 1}
      }
   
    ]
```

To something like this :

```
{
    'Kyber': {tokenSymbol: 'DAI', avgPrice: 1},
   'Bamboo Relay': {tokenSymbol: 'DAI',avgPrice: 1}
}
```

Comment: Simply iterate the array and add the properties of each object to a single result. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Can an object have multiple key-value pairs? What should be done in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
const data = 
        [ { 'Kyber': { tokenSymbol: 'DAI', avgPrice: 1} } 
        , { 'Bamboo Relay': { tokenSymbol: 'DAI', avgPrice: 1} } 
        ] 
const result = data.reduce((a,c)=>
        {
        for (const [k,v] of Object.entries(c)) a[k]={...v} 
        return a
        }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by iterate through the array of object, and for each object, merge that object to the result object. Below solution could help you

```js
const data = [
  {
    Kyber: { tokenSymbol: 'DAI', avgPrice: 1 }
  },
  {
    'Bamboo Relay': { tokenSymbol: 'DAI', avgPrice: 1 }
  }
]

const res = {}
data.forEach(obj => {
  Object.assign(res, obj)
})

console.log(res)
```